# Bootstrap is not working in laravel react ui

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, bootstrap-4

I've set up my new laravel project with react UI using `php artisan ui react`. Did the npm install and `npm run dev`. Added the react id and script link to the welcome.blade.php. now the example react component is loading but bootstrap styling isn't present at that page. my codes are below,
app.js:

```js
require('./bootstrap');



require('./components/Example');
```

Example.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Example() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
                <div className="col-md-8">
                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="card-header">Example Component</div>

                        <div className="card-body">I'm an example component!</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Example;

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

I'm using laravel 8.12. Am I missing something?

Comment: looks like you might be missing a css component to it.  also if you are in react I would pull in bootstrap-react so you can add <Card> components in https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

Comment: where do i add the css component? in example.js or in blade file. I am confused because every tutorial or video I've seen they are getting bootstrap styling just after the initial setup.

Comment: `import './<pathToStyle>/bootstrap.css';`. and don't forget that bootstrap needs jquery for many components to function properly, thought I doubt the card does ... and it would be in example.js

Comment: @RyanH Thank you for the help. I solved it by adding the proper path of node module bootstrap scss in app.css, it was before `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';` i changed it to `@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` and imported it to my example.js.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include styles:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

to your `welcome.blade.php` view file, where is located `<div id="example"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

I faced issues with Pagination error while using bootstrap ui.

Additionally, I will suggest adding this code to AppServiceProvider.

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
{
     Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```